# Pursuers (a game)

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory

From pure entertainment I am interested in the following questions:

> Let $N$ (particularly $N=1$ case is special) pursuers pursue running
>   at max speed $u$ a runner running at max speed $v$.
>
> What is the min $v/u$ with which the runner may be not "caught" by the
>   pursuers (that is may not be in the same point as at least one of the
>   pursuers) during infinite time?

The question may be asked for a circle or for a $A\times B$ rectangle in which movements of the runner and the pursuers are limited to be inside it.

Well, I guess that this problem may probably be hard for modern mathematics. Was it solved?

Comment: Are we talking some round based game here? What are the initial positions? What are the initial velocity vectors? How are positions updated? Why should modern maths (or rather physics) have a problem?

Comment: I don't know what is "round based". I ask whether initial positions, for which the runner may run infinitely, exist. In other words, initial positions can be taken arbitrarily. Initial velocity vectors are allowed to be arbitrary (as much that they are less $v$ for the runners and $u$ for the pursuers). Positions follow a differential equation for some continuous speed functions, that is are updated continuously.

Comment: A round based game is something like chess or poker, where the game is advancing in rounds, where each player makes his moves and then the next player. I had the impression you were after something like Zeno's paradox on [Achilles and the tortoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise). I am not sure if I got your game rules.

Comment: @mvw The trajectory of the runner is any integral of an integrable vector function whose absolute value at every point is not above $v$. Likewise for pursuers (but with $u$ instead of $v$). If the runner's trajectory intersects one of a pursuer, the runner lose.

Comment: @mvw The runner chooses arbitrary starting positions for both himself and for the pursuers.